# The backcolor of the selected ExtJs4 tree node dissapeared after check/uncheck node. How to bring it back?

Tags: tree, extjs4

When a user checks/unchecks tree node it loses it's backcolor. 
It is still selected now. But a user couldn't see it.  How could we bring back the selected backcolor class?

Comment: Hi Krasilov, welcome to StackOverflow. You are only likely to get some answers if you post some code / screen shot. It is next to impossible to even speculate on what your problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in Ext 4.1.1 - supposedly it is fixed in 4.1.2 but it is not yet publicly available.

For a temporary fix I changed the lines 724-735 in view/Table.js to the following:

```
if (oldRowDom.mergeAttributes) {
   var tmpCls = oldRowDom.className;
    oldRowDom.mergeAttributes(newRow, true);
} else {
   var tmpCls = oldRowDom.getAttribute('class');
    newAttrs = newRow.attributes;
    attLen = newAttrs.length;
    for (i = 0; i < attLen; i++) {
        attName = newAttrs[i].name;
        if (attName !== 'id') {
            oldRowDom.setAttribute(attName, newAttrs[i].value);
        }
    }
}
if(tmpCls){
    oldRow.addCls(tmpCls);
}
```